why do I get error using Grpc when I import proto path to my PackageDefinition?
hello I have this problem within the file path and I checked the path it's 100% correct and the file is within the same directory that I'm importing:
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { MicroserviceOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { join } from 'path';
import * as protoLoader from '@grpc/proto-loader';
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import { FilmsModule } from './films.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  try {
    const protoPath = join(__dirname, './proto/films.proto');

    // Load the proto definition
    const options = {
      keepCase: true,
      longs: String,
      enums: String,
      defaults: true,
      oneofs: true,
    };


    const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(protoPath, options);
    const filmsProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);

    // Create the NestJS microservice
    const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(FilmsModule, {
      transport: Transport.GRPC,
      options: {
        package: 'films',
        protoPath: protoPath,
        url: '0.0.0.0:50051',
      },
    });

    await app.listen();
    console.log('Films microservice is listening on port 50051');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error starting Films microservice:', err);
    process.exit(1); // Exit with error code
  }
}

bootstrap();

the error message is
backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-grpc.js:234
        const invalidProtoError = new invalid_proto_definition_exception_1.InvalidProtoDefinitionException(err.path);
                                  ^

Error: The invalid .proto definition (file at "/Users/golden/Desktop/FilmKRD/film-krd backend/proto/films.proto" not found)
at ClientGrpcProxy.loadProto (/Users/golden/Desktop/FilmKRD/film-krd backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-grpc.js:234:39)
at ClientGrpcProxy.createClients (/Users/golden/Desktop/FilmKRD/film-krd backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-grpc.js:211:34)
at new ClientGrpcProxy (/Users/golden/Desktop/FilmKRD/film-krd backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-grpc.js:33:33)
at Function.create (/Users/golden/Desktop/FilmKRD/film-krd backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/client/client-proxy-factory.js:30:24)
at ListenersController.assignClientsToProperties (/Users/golden/Desktop/FilmKRD/film-krd backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/listeners-controller.js:98:47)
at /Users/golden/Desktop/FilmKRD/film-krd backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module.js:52:42
at Map.forEach ()
at MicroservicesModule.bindClients (/Users/golden/Desktop/FilmKRD/film-krd backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module.js:50:15)
at /Users/golden/Desktop/FilmKRD/film-krd backend/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module.js:43:18
at ModulesContainer.forEach ()
golden@Hiwas-MacBook film-krd backend %

The error is slightly ambiguous "invalid .proto definition" and "films.proto not found". It's difficult to remotely debug issues on here but I'd encourage you to verify these errors and assume that the software is reporting the error correctly.
